# Calling a datetime object as string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a slice function in Python that slices parse dates like "1960-01-01". I have tried to assign variables to make the code generic, However, when the data is not called like this :

```
calibration_period = slice('1960-01-01', '2000-12-31')
validation_period = slice('2001-01-01', '2014-12-31')
```

and called like:

```
calibration_period = slice(Base, Date[-1])
validation_period = slice(Date2[0],Date2[-1])
```

The last value is read as 2014-12-31 00:00:00, but I want to read it as "2014-12-31" so the calculations continue up to 2014-12-31 23:00:00.

I have used this:

```
from datetime import datetime
t=pd.to_datetime(str(Date2[-1]))
strg=t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

although the print function shows it as 2014-12-31 the print for validation is still:

```
slice(numpy.datetime64('2001-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'), Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'), None)
```

I would be really grateful if someone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you're mixing up datetime formats and string formats.

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.strptime('01/01/2010', '%d/%m/%Y')
newtime = datetime.strftime(time, '%d/%m/%Y')

print(time, newtime)
```

---

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00 01/01/2010
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Convert your date times to a string with the format you want using datetime.strftime, then you can use logic to do the calculation, i.e:

A datetime object with value 2010-01-01 23:30:00 will always be converted to a string of type 2010-01-01 when using:

```
value = datetime.strftime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Can then perform logic on the two strings

```
if value == newtime:
    print(value)
```

Full example:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.strptime('01/01/2010 20:30:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
newtime = datetime.strftime(time, '%d/%m/%Y')

print(time)
print(newtime)
```

---

```
#Outputs:
2010-01-01 20:30:30
01/01/2010
```

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.utcnow()
>>> d.date()
datetime.date(2018, 7, 10)
>>> str(d.date())
'2018-07-10'
```